# NPM cannot run dev in Docker Node container due to root owned files

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

When I run `npm run development` I am getting the error:

```
Creating api_node_run ... done

> dev
> npm run development

npm WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile  error cleaning log files [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
npm WARN logfile   errno: -13,
npm WARN logfile   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN logfile   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN logfile   path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile }

> development
> mix

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:33 "/root/.npm"

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /root/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 10.2.5
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.5
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.2.5 to update!
npm notice
```

I have a Docker Node container defined in `docker-compose.yml` as:

```
node:
    image: connectedplaces/api/node
    build:
      context: ./docker/node
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
# Set base image.
FROM node:16.20

# Install git for faster package downloads.
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN chown -R node:node /root/.npm

# Set the working directory to the project root.
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

The container will launch successfully, and if I check the permissions with:

```
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint ""  node ls -lart /root/.npm
```

The output is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 node node 4096 Sep  7 22:33 _logs
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Sep  7 22:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 node node 4096 Sep  7 22:33 .
```

I followed the ideas from [Node Docker can't run dev command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750780/node-docker-cant-run-dev-command) but I still cannot get around this error.
I have deleted the local image and rebuilt it, I have bumped the Node version in the Dockerfile and rebuilt, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas what to do next?

Comment: I'd just run `npm run development` directly on your host system, without involving Docker at all.  Is there any reason you need your development tools in an isolated environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze It has to run in a container as that forms part of the CI deployment

Comment: In a CI environment, you don't need a live-reloading environment.  You should delete the Compose `volumes:` so that your CI system is actually running the image it's building.  That will also often avoid permission problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every solution suggested the only one that worked was to create a new cache directory and set `npm_config_cache` to it in the Dockerfile:

```
# Set base image.
FROM node:16.20

# Install git for faster package downloads.
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/.npm \
&& chown -R node:node /home/node/app/.npm

ENV npm_config_cache /home/node/app/.npm

# Set the working directory to the project root.
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

This was suggested in [Error "Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm" while "npx create-react-app example_app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437833/error-your-cache-folder-contains-root-owned-files-due-to-a-bug-in-previous-ver) by @ASHBRN-PHNX Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "chowning" everything so it fits, it should make things better by using the "node" users uid and gid as build arguments. Consider:

```
FROM node:16.20
ARG UID=1001
ARG GID=1001

RUN groupmod -g ${GID} node && usermod -u ${UID} -g ${GID} node

USER node

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

and

```yaml
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=501
        - GID=501
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

for example.

This way you could use the host users uid and gid for development (On macos it is often 501, on Ubuntu 1000/1001 I think). In prod - ypu can just use the default.

Comment: So if my local user ID is 1002, does that mean I can't use this image?  Hard-coding this in the Dockerfile so that the image is tied to one specific host setup doesn't seem like a best practice.

Comment: It is not hard coded. It is passed as a build arg. If your local user has the uid 1002 - this would go as a build arg in your docker-compose.yml.